# How to push an object into an object inside an array?

Tags: typescript

`this.todaysOrders` is an array of `order` objects, with an `itemId` element. I use this `id` to find the `item` object, and then I want to insert it into the `order` object inside `this.todaysOrders` where `order.itemId === item.id`

```
    this.todaysOrders.forEach((subElement: any) => {
      this.itemsService.find(subElement.itemId).subscribe((subRes: any) => {
       // subRes.body here is the retrieved item object, to be inserted 
       // into the corresponding order object with the same itemId 
       // inside this.todaysOrders
      })
    });
```

My end goal is just to iterate over my orders, and have access for the `item` object corresponding to the `itemId` within `order` objects.

This is how the array looks like:

```
todaysOrders = [
    { 
      id: number,
      orderCode: string,
      element1: string,
      .
      .
      .
      itemId: number
    },
    {
    ...
    },
    .
    .
    .
]
```

And I want it to look like this when I'm done:

```
todaysOrders = [
    { 
      id: number,
      orderCode: string,
      element1: string,
      .
      .
      .
      itemId: number,
      item: {
         id: number,
         code: string,
         name: string,
         .
         .
         .
      }
    },
    {
    ...
    },
    .
    .
    .
]
```

Comment: Where does the order item that you want to insert come from? You haven't made that clear.

Comment: @spender from here `this.itemsService.find(subElement.itemId).subscribe((subRes: any)` - the subRes.body is my item object!

Comment: In light of better understanding your question, I deleted my original answer and reposted.

Comment: Your original answer actually worked exactly how I wanted it to work, so thank you so much. But your new answer actually showed me what's wrong with my code to begin with, and seems like a better practice to follow, so I will accept it! (but may be add the old answer on top, then elaborate with new answer?) @spender

Comment: I don't know the sematics of that `subscribe` function, but usually where I see `subscribe` I'm on the lookout for an `unsubscribe`... otherwise the subscriptions array of the emitter will hang on to otherwise orphaned listeners (i.e. a leak)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's assume that you have a type `Order` representing values in `todaysOrders`. Let's also assume that the item you want to attach has a type `OrderItem`

You want to transform your `Order` into

```
type OrderWithItem = Order & {item: OrderItem}
```

but the act of assembling these new items must happen asynchronously.

So we can use the tooling afforded to us by the Promises API to coordinate the asynchronicity in a terse and well-understood way.

First, we can convert the asynchronous part into a bunch of promises.

We create an array of `Promise<OrderWithItem>`

```
const promises = this.todaysOrders.map((subElement: Order) => 
  new Promise<OrderWithItem>((resolve)=>{
    this.itemsService.find(subElement.itemId).subscribe((subRes: any) => {
      // subscriptions usually need to be unsubscribed, right?
      // do whatever to get your item
      // then mash it with the existing element
      resolve({...subElement, item});
    })
  }));
```

then we wait for each promise in the array above to resolve and...

```
const ordersWithItems: OrderWithItem[] = await Promise.all(promises);
```

Of course, this will need to happen in the context of an `async` function.

**EDIT: MY original answer:**

You haven't told us much about how the value of item is obtained, but I suspect you're looking for something like:

```
const todaysOrdersWithItem = 
  todaysOrders.map(order => ({...order, item: orders[order.itemId]}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object structures are not really clear for external folks.

You could iterate over todaysOrders and transfer the data into a new array. Example for the item's ID:

```
newTodaysOrders[index].item.id = 10;
```

Or

```
newTodaysOrders[index].item = { id: 10; code: 'code', ... }
```

That might be it already. I cannot give more help as long as we know nothing more about your types of the objects and so on.